# How to restore default seed generation in SeedRandom[] when specifying method?

Tags: random

I want to generate low-discrepancy sequences and for that purpose I use `SeedRandom[]`, like:

```
BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[(* ..., *) Method -> {"MKL", Method -> {"Sobol", "Dimenstion"->2}}];
RandomReal[1,10]]
```

The problem is that `RandomReal[]` returns the same sequence always as if I set the seed to some fixed number.

My **question** is: what should I put as argument to `SeedRandom[]` in order to restore the default behaviour or how could I change the method without affecting the way the generator is seeded ?

**EDIT**: One work-around would be to calculate a bunch of seeds with, say, `seeds = RandomInteger[2^32]` before calling `SeedRandom[]` for the 1st time and subsequently feed them to the latter.

Comment: "The problem is that RandomReal[] returns the same sequence always as if I set the seed to some fixed number." — Isn't that the whole point of using `BlockRandom`/`SeedRandom`? Why are you using them if you do not want the same sequence?

Comment: Hm? I use `SeedRandom[]` to change the method of how random numbers are generated and `BlockRandom[]` to not affect the generator in the rest of my notebook.

Comment: Can't you remove the `SeedRandom` option completely?

Comment: Not really since I don't know any other way to change the method of random number generation.

Comment: Try `BlockRandom[SeedRandom[Method -> ...]; SeedRandom[]; ...]`.  The second `SeedRandom` resets the seed using the time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put [`SeedRandom[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SeedRandom.html), the seed will be reset using the time of day.  This gives a new starting point to the random generator at the time of execution.  One can use `SeedRandom[Method -> ...]` to set the method first, if desired.

Example:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[Method -> {"MKL", Method -> {"Sobol", "Dimension"->2}}];
  SeedRandom[];
  RandomReal[1,10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SeedRandom` without the first argument to change the method (without changing the way it is seeded) by specifying only the `Method` (and not the actual seed). For example:

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "Congruential"]
RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]

SeedRandom[Method -> "ExtendedCA"]
RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]
```

Comment: That would work unless I enclose it into a BlockRandom[] construct.